# In the following code why does the last line of execution give an error?

Tags: class, oop, instance, python-3.4

In the following code why does the last line of execution give an error ? Shouldn't the dot operator in x.bf() pass on the instance 'x' to the function bf ( like x.af() would ) ?

```
class A:
    a = 6
    def af (self):
        return "Hello-People"

class B:
    b = 7
    def bf (self):
        return "Bye-People"

>>> x = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> x.bf = B.bf
>>> x.bf()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x.bf = B.bf is your error, because B is a class, not an instance of the object.

You can't assign x.bf directly to the class.
You need to assign x.bf to the instance 'b.bf' or instantiate the class properly

ie. Either change that line to:

```
# Where we instantiated class B and invoke bf via lazy loading (loading at the last possible minute)
x.bf = B().bf
```

or

```
# Use the existing instance of B and call bf
x.bf = b.bf
```

More information:

1. A and B are your classes. They don't do anything until you instantiate them.
2. x and b are your object instances. x is an instance of A, and b is an instance of B
3. Whenever you instantiate a class, you need to conform to it's constructor signature. In this case, the classes require no additional parameters besides self. However, self only gets passed if the class is invoked via ();

   'x = A()' and 'b = B()' conform to that signature

   The error you encountered is basically python telling you that you called something, a function or a class without passing in a required variable.

Comment: Could please you explain why this happens in further detail.

Comment: But in the last line, x.bf(), x is an instance variable. So shouldn't it pass self to bf ?

Comment: Correct. The last line can be either written as x.bf or x.bf(). I chose to leave it as x.bf(), because personal preference is to always invoke a function and indicate that it's function signature is being fulfilled. x.bf() tells me that I am calling bf() on the object x, and it needs no additional parameters.

Comment: Okay. I'm kind of confused. What does B.bf bind to x.bf (in the second last line) ? If it is the function definition of bf from B, then wouldn't it pass x as the self argument to x.bf(), thus not giving an error ?

Comment: x.bf has nothing on it to begin with. x.bf is just a variable on the object x. The statement(s) "x.bf = B().bf" or "x.bf() = b.bf" basically tell python to assign the RETURNED value of B().bf or b.bf to x.bf. Does that make sense? Your original error was being thrown because you cannot call B.bf. You need to instantiate B() and then call bf, thus the solution B().bf.